# Unable to show latest Admob in android

Tags: android, admob

> I have been trying to implement new Admob.

Steps I follow.

**1. Add to project level**

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.3.4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**3. Added internet permision to manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**4. Also added meta-data to Manifest**

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

**2. Added this to build level**

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

But Ads are not showing. And log cat shows.

```
15:38:09.025 3820-3820/droidudes.eightballfree D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraMobileAdsSettingManagerCreatorImpl
08-13 15:38:10.540 3820-3820/droidudes.eightballfree D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
08-13 15:38:10.735 3820-3820/droidudes.eightballfree I/Ads: Starting ad request.
08-13 15:38:10.740 3820-3820/droidudes.eightballfree I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("2EB0695D3EBA40CD8E9084AF03AABBAF") to get test ads on this device.
08-13 15:38:13.350 3820-3820/droidudes.eightballfree D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
08-13 15:38:13.380 3820-3820/droidudes.eightballfree I/Ads: Starting ad request.
08-13 15:38:13.380 3820-3820/droidudes.eightballfree I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("2EB0695D3EBA40CD8E9084AF03AABBAF") to get test ads on this device.
08-13 15:38:13.445 3820-3820/droidudes.eightballfree D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
08-13 15:38:13.450 3820-3820/droidudes.eightballfree I/Ads: Starting ad request.
08-13 15:38:13.450 3820-3820/droidudes.eightballfree I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("2EB0695D3EBA40CD8E9084AF03AABBAF") to get test ads on this device.
08-13 15:38:13.515 3820-3820/droidudes.eightballfree D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
08-13 15:38:13.515 3820-3820/droidudes.eightballfree I/Ads: Starting ad request.
08-13 15:38:13.515 3820-3820/droidudes.eightballfree I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("2EB0695D3EBA40CD8E9084AF03AABBAF") to get test ads on this device.
08-13 15:38:13.585 3820-3820/droidudes.eightballfree I/Adds: addLoaded
08-13 15:38:18.200 3820-3839/droidudes.eightballfree W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
08-13 15:38:18.205 3820-3838/droidudes.eightballfree W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
08-13 15:38:18.210 3820-3820/droidudes.eightballfree W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
08-13 15:38:18.210 3820-3820/droidudes.eightballfree W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
08-13 15:38:18.225 3820-4153/droidudes.eightballfree W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
08-13 15:38:18.225 3820-3820/droidudes.eightballfree W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
08-13 15:38:24.090 3820-3839/droidudes.eightballfree W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
08-13 15:38:24.090 3820-3820/droidudes.eightballfree W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

Comment: Could you please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to use `addTestDevice` for testing of `Ads` using `deviceId`.Copy the `deviceId` and add it to `AdRequest` as shown below

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                // Check the LogCat to get your test device ID
                .addTestDevice("2EB0695D3EBA40CD8E9084AF03AABBAF")
                .build();
```

Comment: how to get deviceId and why my ads aren't showing ?

Comment: And my app is on playstore. I simply wanna replace with new sdk and publish.

Comment: @Nepster Device id you will get in your `Logat`.